Invalidate Authentication Cookies on remote machines
I've got an ASP.NET Core application. When a user signs into their account on COMPUTER-B I want to sign them out of the application on COMPUTER-A (and any other computer they may be on).
Since I track the user's Session IDs in my database, I would think I could sign them out by deleting the row from the SQL Distributed Cache table that is associated with the Session ID on COMPUTER-A.
The issue is that the "ID" column in the SQL Distributed Cache table does not match the HttpContext.Current.Session.ID value.
How can I clear cache entries for a session that is not the current session?

What you're describing is stateful auth - and it doesn't scale (also, I detest websites that limit me to a single browser - it's user-hostile and does not improve security, seriously). Why are you doing this?

Also, you're incorrectly conflating Session-State with Authentication - the two are entirely separate in ASP.NET Core (i.e. you can be unauthenticated (anonymous) and have Session-State - and you can be authenticated while Session-State is entirely disabled on the server): so the ISession.Id value has no bearing on one's auth status.

"SQL Distributed Cache tabl" - this is a misnomer: there is nothing "distributed" about (ab)using an RDBMS as a high-latency and single-point-of-failure storage bucket for ISession.

The application I'm working with needs to be compliant with some government rules, and this is a requirement. It helps ensure users don't share credentials. The Session ID is apparently used as the Key for the SQL Distributed Cache (But if it is, I don't see how).

Please satiate my curiosity: if not FIPS, may I ask which regulation or requirement are you referring to?

Looks like I’ve got myself a new bedtime read!
